# circular dependency dropped on more than one executables in make file

Tags: makefile, circular-dependency

```
exe = mp1
exe2 = compare

mp1: $(exe)
compare: $(exe2)

COMPILER = g++
COMPILER_OPTS = -c -g

LINKER = g++
LINKER_OPTS = 

common_objs = EasyBMP.o 
exe_objs = main.o
exe2_objs = compare.o

$(exe) : $(common_objs) $(exe_objs)
    $(LINKER) $(LINKER_OPTS) $^ -o $@

$(exe2) : $(common_objs) $(exe2_objs)
    $(LINKER) $(LINKER_OPTS) $^ -o $@


EasyBMP.o : EasyBMP.h EasyBMP.cpp EasyBMP_BMP.h EasyBMP_DataStructures.h EasyBMP_VariousBMPutilities.h
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_OPTS) EasyBMP.cpp
main.o : main.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_OPTS) main.cpp
compare.o : compare.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_OPTS) compare.cpp

clean:
    -rm *.o $(exe)
```

I'm getting circular dependency dropped when i do make compare or make mp1. what's the problem??

Also can you explain what "%^" macro means exactly ??

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd tell us _which_ circular dependency is dropped.  Pasting the exact error message you get should be the very first thing you do when you want to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
exe = mp1
exe2 = compare

mp1: $(exe)
compare: $(exe2)
```

So, after expanding the variables, this is:

```
mp1: mp1
compare: compare
```

This means "to build mp1, you must first build mp1, and to build compare, you must first build compare".  Hence, circular dependencies.

I don't know what you mean by `%^`.  Maybe you mean `$^`?  Look up [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in the GNU make manual.

Answer (score 0):

You have mp1 and compare defined as conditions on your line 3 and 4 that is causing the circular dependency.